# C# cryptography: Certificate chain is OK on Windows but fails on Linux: "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: c#, linux, cryptography, x509certificate

I am writing C# code that deals with certificates. I have a certificate chain which terminates in a self-signed root. On Windows, my code works fine, but on Linux it fails. I get an **X509ChainStatus** object containing status **X509ChainStatusFlags.PartialChain** and the status information *unable to get local issuer certificate*.

My code looks like this:

```
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = GetCertificateCollectionFromResource(X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);
    var leaf = collection[0];
    var parents = new[] { collection[1], collection[2] };
    var chain = CreateChain(parents);
    var valid = chain.Build(leaf);
    if (!valid)
        throw new Exception("Chain.Build returned false");

    // We expect the root to be untrusted. It is a self-signed certificate. So the UntrustedRoot flag is harmless.
    var illegalFlags = chain.ChainStatus.Where(f => f.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot).ToList();
    if (illegalFlags.Any())
    {
        var firstIllegalFlag = illegalFlags.First();
        throw new Exception($"Illegal status flag found: {firstIllegalFlag.Status} ({firstIllegalFlag.StatusInformation})");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Certificate collection is valid!");
    }
```

I have a full working example here (containing just the public parts of all the certificates): https://github.com/CAP-3Shape/CertificateValidatorSample

When I run the sample on Windows using `dotnet run`, it works. When I run it on Linux I get this:

> Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Illegal status flag found: PartialChain (unable to get local issuer certificate)
> at ClausAppel.CertificateValidatorSample.Program.InstanceMain() in /home/devops/actions-runner/work/Raven.KeyManagementService/Raven.KeyManagementService/CertificateValidatorSample/Program.cs:line 30
> at ClausAppel.CertificateValidatorSample.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/devops/actions-runner/work/Raven.KeyManagementService/Raven.KeyManagementService/CertificateValidatorSample/Program.cs:line 13

Does anyone know what to do about this? Might I need to install some software or make other changes to my Linux machine?

I could allow this particular status flag, but I very much don't want to do that. That would introduce a lot of false negatives (i.e., chains that are not valid but which would look valid if we allow this status flag).

I have tried to add the parent certificates using **X509Store**, but that didn't seem to help.

**EDIT**: The problem does not happen on every Linux machine. I have seen it happen on some Linux machines running Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) and Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish). But I have also seen it pass on some machines running Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa). So it apparently depends on the settings and software installed on the Linux runner.

Comment: Not reproducible? (Works fine on Ubuntu 20.04).  Your end-entity certificate has a made-up extension `2.25.29.1.2.34` and doesn't have an Authority Key Identifier extension, which may be contributing, but nothing is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: My leaf certificate contained **X509KeyUsageFlags.None**. Apparently some newer cryptography libraries consider this an error. When we changed our certificates to use another flag, they started working on all Linux versions.

I was able to reproduce the error on the following Linux Docker images:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine

mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-jammy
```

This Linux Docker image would accept the certificate even with **X509KeyUsageFlags.None**:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal
```

See also:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/17ppihk/c_cryptography_certificate_chain_is_ok_on_windows/
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2492375